# Visual Studio Setup Project Missing Dependency

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

I've taking over a Visual Studio 2017 project from a previous developer.
Solution basically has two projects.  One project is the application project and the other is the Setup Project for a end-user to install the application.

When I compile the setup project, I get a missing dependency.  Developer notes say to keep local copy = false for the dependency in question.  I even tried making it true and it failed.

How would I resolve this dependency issue.  The file missing basically is a 3rd party DLL that is needed to run the application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[visual studio project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMDIQ.jpg)

Comment: By default the dll is included in the setup. Try to check if the dll's `Exclude` property is `False` by `Application Folder -> dll that need to include -> right-click -> Properties Window -> Exclude`

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kyle.   I looked in the application folder of the setup project and the DLL isn't in their.  If I manually add the DLL it adds a whole bunch of other dependencies errors out when compiling.    The PDK is don't copy in the application project, so it doesn't copy to the setup project.  Developers notes state this is how it should be.

Comment: I'm going to close this question.  Apparently this is how its suppose to work.  The reason the dll is missing is because it should use the one installed on the machine where the software containing the dll exists.